# Count zeroes between two non-zero number and then continue doing this through the array of numbers in R

Tags: r

Lets say we have this following data:

```
a <- c(0.1,0.2,0,0,0,0,1.2,1.4,0,0,1.4)
b <- c(0,0,0,1.1,0,0,0,0,0.25,0.51,0)
```

Now I would like to count the zeroes between two non-zero numbers and continue the count in consequent non-zero numbers. So, the output would look like
for a it would be an array of (4,2)
for b it would be an array of (3,4,1)

I tried counting zeroes with general filtering codes, but I can't replicate the code for the consequent non-zero-zero numbers.

Here is the precipitation dataset I am dealing with:
[image: precipitation data]

I want to count the number of days between precipitation events. Maybe this will make the question clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use run-length encoding (`rle`):

```r
a <- c(0.1,0.2,0,0,0,0,1.2,1.4,0,0,1.4)
b <- c(0,0,0,1.1,0,0,0,0,0.25,0.51,0)

with(unclass(rle(a)), lengths[values == 0])
#> [1] 4 2
with(unclass(rle(b)), lengths[values == 0])
#> [1] 3 4 1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, it worked. How is it possible to do the same (finding zeroes between non-zero numbers (greater than 0.1)?

Comment: @SumonDatta do you mean the same as above, except count all days of 0.1 or less as if they were 0? That would be `with(unclass(rle(a < 0.2)), lengths[values == "TRUE"])`

Comment: Let me try that. But what I wanted to get is the number of days between precipitation events >0.1 inches.

Comment: Seems like this did the trick:

```dwp_original <- with(unclass(rle(a>0.1)), lengths[values == 0])```

Comment: One ore question: How can I get the arrays with respect to years? Use for loop? If yes, how?

Comment: I tried a lot of do find the array with respect to years, but in vain. Any way to do that?

Comment: @SumonDatta your example data doesn't have any years in it, so I don't know what you mean. Perhaps give a sample of your actual data?